Session Not Created : This Version of Chrome Driver Only supports Chrome Version 126
In my Selenium vba code after chrome update the browser for 129.0.6668.59 the code stopped working as the below error, I downloaded the same version chrome driver and copy it and replace it with the old one and still showing the same error.

I downloaded the same version chrome driver and copy it and replace it with the old one and still showing the same error.
[
